# Undefined variable $districts, but the $provinces and $regencies is work

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller

I do not need the model as I see `$province` and `$regencies` working, but the `$districts` and `$villages` are not defined.

**Controller**

```
class LocationController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $provinces = DB::table('reg_provinces')->pluck('name');
        $regencies = DB::table('reg_regencies')->pluck('name');
        $districts = DB::table('reg_districts')->pluck('name');
        $villages = DB::table('reg_villages')->pluck('name');

        return view('index',
            ['provinces' => $provinces],
            ['regencies' => $regencies],
            ['districts' => $districts],
            ['villages' => $villages],
        );
    }
}
```

**View**

```
     <div class="dropend mb-3">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          Select Province
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
          @foreach ($provinces as $province)
            <li class="dropdown-item">{{ $province }}</li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="dropend mb-3">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          Select City
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
          @foreach ($regencies as $regency)
            <li class="dropdown-item">{{ $regency }}</li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="dropend mb-3">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          Select District
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
          @foreach ($districts as $district)
            <li class="dropdown-item">{{ $district }}</li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="dropend mb-3">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          Select Subdistrict
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
          @foreach ($villages as $village)
            <li class="dropdown-item">{{ $village }}</li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: There is a reason why you have to enter a certain %age of text. Its so you actually FULLY describe your issue, its not so you can fake it with `Lorem ipsum`

Comment: ALSO, please ALWAYS show us ALL the error message, not a summary that is likely missing out something useful like which file the error is coming from

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to send all of them as one array on the second argument:

```php
class LocationController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $provinces = DB::table('reg_provinces')->pluck('name');
        $regencies = DB::table('reg_regencies')->pluck('name');
        $districts = DB::table('reg_districts')->pluck('name');
        $villages = DB::table('reg_villages')->pluck('name');

        return view('index',
            [
              'provinces' => $provinces,
              'regencies' => $regencies,
              'districts' => $districts,
              'villages' => $villages
             ],
        );
    }
}
```